# Resize a layout on onLayout call

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a linear layout inside horizontal scrollview which I want to adjust padding according to its contents. I'm using onLayout call of horizontal scrollview.

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if(null != views && views.size() > 0) {
            int paddingLeft = (getWidth()/2) - (views.get(0).getWidth()/2);
            int paddingRight = (getWidth()/2) - (views.get(views.size()-1).getWidth()/2);
            content.setPadding(getPaddingLeft() + paddingLeft, getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight() + paddingRight, getPaddingBottom());
        }
        content.invalidate();
    }
```

I have logged all of the sizes and all seems to be accurate except padding. Padding on content is not visible until I change the visibility of the view again. As you can see I tried to invalidate the content but still width of the layout is without the padding before it re-drawn again. Is it possible to force draw ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting the padding value in onLayout and set it before drawing it, hope it helps someone else.

```
 @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        FLog.d("Information", "onLayout");
        if(null != views && views.size() > 0) {
            paddingLeft = (getWidth()/2) - (views.get(0).getWidth()/2);
            paddingRight = (getWidth()/2) - (views.get(views.size()-1).getWidth()/2);
            FLog.i("Information", "[paddingRight]" + paddingRight + " = " + " ([scrollView width]" + getWidth() + " / 2) " + " - " + "[viewLast width]" + views.get(views.size()-1).getWidth() + " / 2)");
            FLog.i("Information", "ContentWidth: " + content.getWidth());
            paddingInitialized = true;
        }
        content.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(!paddingSet && paddingInitialized) {
            content.setPadding(getPaddingLeft() + paddingLeft, getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight() + paddingRight, getPaddingBottom());
            paddingSet = true;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```